# C++ using unordered_map with custom class as key, providing Hash functor and equality functor

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I understand that when using an unordered_map/unordered_set with a custom class as the key, I will need to provide a hash function for the key and a function to compare if two keys are equivalent. However, I haven't been able to figure out why my set up below is not working:

```
struct RandomListNode {
    int label;
    RandomListNode *next, *random;
    RandomListNode(int x) : label(x), next(NULL), random(NULL) {}
};

struct MyHash {
    size_t operator()(const RandomListNode& node) const {
        return (size_t)(&node) + node.label;
    }
};

struct KeyEqual {
    bool operator()(const RandomListNode& node1, const RandomListNode& node2) const {
        return (&node1 == &node2) && (node1.label == node2.label);
    }
};

...

unordered_map<RandomListNode, RandomListNode, MyHash, KeyEqual> originalToCopy;
```

gives me

```
11. In instantiation of template class 'std::__1::unordered_map<RandomListNode, RandomListNode, std::__1::hash<RandomListNode>, std::__1::equal_to<RandomListNode>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const RandomListNode, RandomListNode> > >' requested here
```

**EDIT 1**

I think I found out the reason why it didn't work before:

I was doing

```
    for (unordered_map<RandomListNode, RandomListNode>::value_type value : originalToCopy)
    {
        value.second.random = &originalToCopy[*(value.first.random)];
    }
```

whereas I should be doing

```
    for (unordered_map<RandomListNode, RandomListNode, MyHash, KeyEqual>::value_type value : originalToCopy)
    {
        value.second.random = &originalToCopy[*(value.first.random)];
    }
```

But there's also another thing that I want to ask about, if the `RandomListNode` class does not provide a default constructor, or copy constructor, or move constructor and it's a class that I cannot modify, is it true that I cannot make `operator[]` or `emplace()` work with the `unordered_map` class when a key doesn't exist and I want to create one?

Comment: That doesn't look like the full and complete error output. Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output. Then mark out (with e.g. a comment) *where* in the code you show the error is.

Comment: On an unrelated note regarding your `KeyEqual` structure, if `&node1 == &node2` is true, then it follows that `node1.label == node2.label` is true as well (since `node1` is the exact same object as `node2`).

Comment: Sorry. I will try to update with the full error output later.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Updated. Apologize for the delay. Wasn't used to posting and monitoring a thread on SO.